# scp not working saying its a directory error

Tags: backup, scp

I am trying to copy a file to remote server in a certain folder.

Its an adrive backup plan. But it comes with scp. I can copy the file if I don't select directory. Even if I put a directory that doesn't exist it says its a directory.

```
root@host1 [/usr/src]# scp ftpdelete.sh user@host@scp.adrive.com:/mysql-only/
scp: /mysql-only/: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 60):

Amazingly enough in my case it was that the directory didn't exists!! :|
Is the error message a bug?... or it's me. Tempted for the latter.

Comment: This strikes me as a decidedly erroneous error message.

Comment: I also experienced this – I made a spelling error, something like foo_bar (this directory doesn’t exist) instead of foo-bar (this directory exists). And I got this error message: “scp: /home/johndoe/foo_bar/: Is a directory”. Quite confusing indeed.

Comment: I think the error message should be "Is a directory name" and means that since the file or directory doesn't exist, it needs to be created, but since you terminated with a '/', you specified a directory name rather than a file name.

Answer (score 20):

SCP doesn't automatically create you new directory if you want to scp file (it creates directory only if you do recursive copy). There is wrong error message. The error should be `No such file or directory` or similar.

It is known problem and there is upstream bugzilla about this [1].

[1] https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1768

Comment: The directory already exists. What I did to get it to work was. puttting a dot before directory. ./mysql-only/

Comment: OK. Just now I noticed that you started your path with `/` which was absolute path and which means that it was not existing. Putting there dot works, but better would be remove `/` from beginning.

Answer (score 7):

You are copying the `sh` file to a new directory on the server, and the directory is expected to be there but in fact not(then the machine thinks you want to change the file to be a directory). Most probably the directory you set is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

-r' Recursively copy entire directories. Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.
But it doesn't create a directory but you can do below

```
ssh remote mkdir /diretcory

root@host1 [/usr/src]# scp -r ftpdelete.sh user@host@scp.adrive.com:/complete_path/mysql-only/
```

or

rsync can do the creating of directory if not exist
its basic command syntax is similar to scp:²

$ rsync -r -e ssh ftpdelete.sh me@my-system:/complete_path/mysql-only/

Comment: Although this code segment might answer the question, you should add an explanation to it.

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

I saw a similar error, when tried `scp` to path that relative to `home` directory. The error fixed after removing unnecessary leading `/` in path:

```
# scp ftpdelete.sh user@host@scp.adrive.com:mysql-only/
```

rather then

```
# scp ftpdelete.sh user@host@scp.adrive.com:/mysql-only/
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scp -r source_location user@servername:/target_location
```

Comment: this will in recursive  way copy to target location.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put "/" after the directory's name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the file directly to your local root directory and then copy it from there :
root@host1 [/usr/src]# scp user@host:/root/Desktop/file.txt /root/home/

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you replied one question and there are additional answers, please try to add the Pros and Cons of your new P.O.V.